# Как из столбца отнять нарастающие значение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Как из значения столбца `col1` отнять число, но чтобы при каждом отнимании оно нарастало: сначала отнять 2, потом 4, потом 6 и т.д.. Но при этом, если 0, то надо пропустить.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [0, 0, 50, 80, 100, 120, 140]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
Out[125]: 
   col1
0     0
1     0
2    50
3    80
4   100
5   120
6   140
```

Пробую так, но эта не верно. Так же пытался применить функцию `.cumsum()`, но выдает ошибку:

```
df["col1"] - 2.cumsum()
```

Вот такой результат должен получиться.

```
   col1
0     0
1     0
2    48
3    76
4    94
5   112
6   130
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mask = df["col1"] != 0
df.loc[mask, "col1"] -= np.arange(1, mask.sum()+1) * 2
```

результат:

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]:
   col1
0     0
1     0
2    48
3    76
4    94
5   112
6   130
```

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем ясна цель, в голову ничего умнее этого не приходит:

```
m = df["col1"].loc[df.index>=1]
df["col1"].loc[df.index>=1] = m.sub(list(range(0,m.size*2,2)))
```

df:

```
   col1
0     0
1     0
2    48
3    76
4    94
5   112
6   130
```